# Sum of discrete uniform variables

Tags: probability

I know that the sum of n real variables between [0, 1] in a uniform distribution is the Irwin-Hall distribution.

But if the variables are discrete uniform (positive) integers in the interval [A, B] and

What is the probability that the sum is greater than M with N variables?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? There is no general explicit formula, I think. So you have to focus on two variables, for instance.

Comment: I did nothing :(

Comment: Not any thought? Start by thinking if it is possible to have a general formula for all values of A and B.

Comment: And the expected value for the number of variables? Would it be possible to calculate? Even if computationally?

Comment: This is no problem, since you know that $\mathbb E(X_i)=\frac{A+B}{2}$

Comment: This is the expected value of X, I want the expected value of n

Comment: You mean the expected value of $X_1+X_2+\ldots + X_n$?